# Iterating through an array to return a id field from the database symfony2 controller method

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to iterate over the arrays from the database doctrine query. On getting the value of the id field, set it as the return type value of the method. On getting the endpoint uri it returns status 200 -  the response is empty

This is my attempt.

```
/**
 * @Route("/get/{email}")
 */
 public function emailAction($email)
 {
     $var = "";
   $singleresult = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Api3Bundle:Influ')->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
   if ($singleresult === null) {
   return new View("user not found", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
   }
//area of problem
   foreach($singleresult as $users)
     {
       $var = $users.id;
     }
 return $var;
//end of area of problem
 }
```

I am trying to use email to return the id. The above attempt show through postman that the response is empty

Comment: `$users.id` is not valid PHP. Also, you are returning a regular value, but you need to return a response!

Comment: please where is my wrong I am new to php/symfony

Comment: `$users->id` [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: the response was empty

Answer (score 0):

If `$singleresult` has just one result, then why are you using foreach() on it?

If `$singleresult` has more than one result, you are going to loop through them all and return the last one (because all previous `$var`'s will be overwritten.

Can't you access it directly `$singleresult->id` without the loop?

If the `id` is empty, perhaps you could start doing some debugging by returning everything inside of `$singleresult` to see why there is no `id`.

Comment: how can I return everything inside of single result can u modify your answer a bit

Comment: I'm suggesting that you don't need the `foreach` or the declaration of `$var`, just use `$singleresult->id`.  If this doesn't work for you, please do a `var_export($singleresult)` and add the data to your question.  If that data is not what you expect to see, then it will be up to you to figure out what the OOP is going on.

Comment: will var_export($singleresult) work in json request. no twig view is attached to the controller as I am returning a json request

Comment: The bottom line is, you have to isolate where the failure is originating.  Do what is necessary to debug and verify what is expected to work.  Let us know what you find.